# How to create a list from a csv file

Tags: file, csv

How I can create a list from a csv file contains a  10000 records with 2 columns like this example 
D2  is the first and " crashes when open multiple pages"

Answer (score 0):

What programming language? Java?

```
public static ArrayList<String> CSVtoArrayList(String csvFilePath) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (csfFilePath != null) {
        String[] splitData = csfFilePath.split("\\s*,\\s*");
        for (int i = 0; i < splitData.length; i++) {
            if (!(splitData[i] == null) || !(splitData[i].length() == 0)) {
                result.add(splitData[i].trim());
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

An ArrayList is already a List, because ArrayList implements the List interface. No casting is necessary.